# Find $\mathbb P(X+Y> z)$ for independent $X\sim U[0,1]$ and $Y \sim \exp(1)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I've seen a lot of answers for when $X$ and $Y$ are both uniformly distributed, but I'm unsure how to apply those to this case, particularly how to find the bounds for the following (if this is the correct way to continue):

$\mathbb P(X+Y>z) = \int \int F_X F_Y dx dy$ for $0\leq z \leq 1$ and $z>1$

I have calculated the convolution, but apparently I don't need to use this so any help on how to go about this in a different way is much appreciated.

---

My attempt is that for $0\leq z\leq 1$, the bounds are $0\leq x \leq 1-y$ and $0\leq y \leq 1$?

Comment: Wouldn't this be the average of $Y$ over $[z-1,z]$?

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to compute this is to condition on $X,$ as $X$ has a simple density function and $\mathbb{P}(Y>y) = e^{-y}$ also has a simple form.

We have 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X+Y > z) &= \int^1_0 \mathbb{P}(X+Y > z  \ | \ X = x)\ p_X(x) \ dx\\
                    &= \int^1_0 \mathbb{P}(Y > z-x) dx \\
                    &= \int^1_0 e^{x-z} dx \\
                    &= e^{-z} (e-1)
\end{align*}

Comment: Is this for $0\leq z \leq 1$? or $z>1$? I need to solve for both cases. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is for $z\geq 1.$ The $z\in [0,1]$ case is the same but a little bit more care is required in thinking about $\int^1_0 \mathbb{P}(Y > z-x) \ dx.$